# Button on the top of list view are not clickable

Tags: android, xml

I am new to android development. Facing below issue any help appreciated.

I have list view and three buttons on top. list view items are clickable but didn't perform any operation on the button click.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dip" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/sellers"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:text="@string/sellers" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buyers"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:text="@string/buyers" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/addTicketButton"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:text="@string/addTicket"
        android:textSize="16sp" />
</LinearLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#FFFFFF" >
</ListView>
```

Here is the controller file

Comment: This is just xml. Have you wired up these buttons with onClickListeners in code?

Comment: As I can see there is no problem in your xml file and also there is no relation between Button click and Listview click.
please post your complete code related to onClick event of Button so that I or anyone here can help you.

Comment: @Nilesh May you post your java code?

Answer (score 0):

change `android:layout_height="fill_parent"` to `0dp` or `wrap_content` and remove the  `android:focusable="false"` from all the buttons

Answer (score 0):

finally found the answer for above question.

You have to add the buttons in the header of the list view.

// Header view for the list LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this); View header = inflater.inflate( R.layout.activity_ticket_list_header, null); Button addTicket = (Button) header.findViewById(R.id.addTicket); Button listBuyers = (Button) header.findViewById(R.id.listBuyers); Button listSellers = (Button) header.findViewById(R.id.listSellers); list.addHeaderView(header);
list.addHeaderView(header);